# How to handle QuotaExceededError in Service worker registration process?

Tags: service-worker

I am getting the following error on startup of my website. This error I see in the chrome://serviceworker-internals/ log. I have attached a picture of it.

[image]

```
Error: {"columnNumber":-1,"lineNumber":-1,"message":"ServiceWorker failed to install: ServiceWorker failed to handle event (event.waitUntil Promise rejected)","sourceURL":""}
Console: {"lineNumber":0,"message":"Uncaught (in promise) QuotaExceededError: Quota exceeded.","message_level":3,"sourceIdentifier":1,"sourceURL":"http://localhost:8100/service-worker.js"}
```

I know this is because low memory space on my OS installed drive. I have tried to handle it by following methods in script file but nothing worked.

```
self.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e.filename, e.lineno, e.colno, e.message);
});


self.onerror = function(message) {
  console.log(message);
};
```

I just want to show user an error message like, "Please free some space from your OS installed directory to run the website". Where should write the code?

Or

I will bypass the service worker. Now it is showing me a blank white page.

Bellow is my service worker registration code.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope : ', registration.scope);
      registration.update();
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect this failure to install because the `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` promise will reject.

Right now the code that you're using has a two-argument `.then()`, and the second argument is the catch handler which will be invoked when there's a failure to install.

It would probably be cleaner to explicitly use `.catch()`, which would make your registration code look like:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').catch(function(error) {
      // Show a message prompting the user to free up space, etc.
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue where the service worker can't install because the OS drive is full, @jeff-posnick's answer is correct.

In the similar case where the '*QuotaExceededError: Quota exceeded.*' error appears because an installed service worker is trying to cache more content than is permitted (or than the drive currently has space for), the solution is to `catch` errors in the same way from any `cache.addAll` and `cache.put` methods.

Using the MDN reference 'Using Service Workers' (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) as an example, the code in `service-worker.js` would look like this:

`cache.addAll`:

```
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v1').then((cache) => {
      return cache.addAll([
        './sw-test/',
        './sw-test/index.html',
        './sw-test/style.css',
        './sw-test/app.js',
        './sw-test/image-list.js',
        './sw-test/star-wars-logo.jpg',
        './sw-test/gallery/',
        './sw-test/gallery/bountyHunters.jpg',
        './sw-test/gallery/myLittleVader.jpg',
        './sw-test/gallery/snowTroopers.jpg'
      ]).catch(error => {
         console.log('Error caching all: ' + error.name + ': ' + error.message);
            //add any further error handling code or message to users here
      });
    })
  );
});
```

...

`cache.put`:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then((resp) => {
      return resp || fetch(event.request).then((response) => {
        return caches.open('v1').then((cache) => {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone()).catch(error => {
            console.log('Error caching resource: ' + e.request.url + ': ' + error.name + ': ' + error.message);
            //add any further error handling code or message to users here
          });

          return response;
        });  
      });
    })
  );
});
```

If memory is low, then making these changes could save seeing the same error again later.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Quota exceeded errors for service workers are typically caused because of a conflict with other service workers. It's the service worker quota not memory quota. If your site is built on  Wordpress just install the Google-developed PWA plugin. PWA was built specifically to work with existing or in-development progressive web apps. You can also visit the PWA repository to get the source code instead. https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/pwa-wp